# My female dog(shih tzu), doesn't want to mate with my other male dog(shih tzu)

Tags: dogs

I think my female shih tzu is the Alpha of the pack in our house. She's already 2 years old. And already had her 2nd heat this year. She's getting angry when my male dogs is humping her. Is there anything I can do, or just let it be?

Answer (score 3):

**If the bitch isn't at the optimum point in her cycle (ovulating) she wont want to.**

There are ways to see if she is at the optimum point in her cycle, these are:

- A progesterone test (a hormone test taken from the blood) which measures for hormone surges. The test returns a number (a score) based on the hormone surge this  score it will tell you if she is at the optimum point in her cycle to breed.
- Or a cytology test (a smear of the vaginal cells and examined under am
  microscope to see if there are changes in the cells) this isnt as
  accurate as the progesterone test.

I recommend that you read on all of this before deciding to breed your dogs.

A good starting point would be [The Book of The Bitch](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Book_of_the_Bitch.html?id=zi_bbk9kUNAC), a very highly regarded book which gives an introduction to breeding for first timers.

I would also ensure all of the relevant and necessary health tests are conducted, make sure the dogs are a suitable match and temperament is suitable for breeding.

To avoid unwanted breeding, separate them when it becomes evident the male is trying to mate. Crate one of them away from the other.